# Unable to get values from xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse through xml and get some values and have tried multiple approaches but i am unable to get the values.

this is what i have tried so far

```
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\one\OneDrive\Desktop\PP\SnippetWithImage.idms";
        string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
        XmlNodeList spreadNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("spread");
        foreach (XmlNode spreadNode in spreadNodes)
        {
            var linkNodes = spreadNode.SelectNodes("//rectangle/image/link");
            foreach (XmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("path : " + linkNode.SelectSingleNode("LinkResourceURI").InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Here spreadNodes count is always 0.

I have tried this with XElements as well and used Decendents but sill the same result.

Here is the xml structure  https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/y22db1f26

the file which i am loading is an InDesign Snippet file. I am trying to get the linkResourceURI property value from links which is a child of image which is a child of rectangle which is a child of spread.

Comment: XPath is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some [quick debugging](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKr8Ea) shows that `spreadNodes` is empty, to start with. The most obvious cause is that the element name is `Spread` not `spread`, and if we make this change, we [see `spreadNodes` has one element](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cWyLhL).

Next, it's obvious that `spreadNode.SelectNodes("//rectangle/image/link")` isn't returning anything. Again, that's probably capitalisation: change it to `//Rectangle/Image/Link`, and we [get a `NullReferenceException`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2s8sxc). Progress, at least.

We're getting that exception because `linkNode.SelectSingleNode("LinkResourceURI")` is returning null. It turns out that's because `LinkResourceURI` is an attribute, and you're looking for an element. Change that to `linkNode.Attributes["LinkResourceURI"].InnerText`, and [everything works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i391iD).

```
XmlNodeList spreadNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Spread");
foreach (XmlNode spreadNode in spreadNodes)
{
    var linkNodes = spreadNode.SelectNodes("//Rectangle/Image/Link");
    foreach (XmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("path : " + linkNode.Attributes["LinkResourceURI"].InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you canton7. I did not knew that it was case sensitive.